# eth0 and wlan0 missing from ifconfig (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, wireless, ethernet

I have been using Ubuntu 16.04 for some time and everything had been working as expected until a couple of days ago. The wifi icon appears at the top right corner of the screen, but when clicked it does not display any network. I also tried connecting via Ethernet, but it does not get detected.

I have done some research on this site but none of the solutions have worked so far. Here are some of the commands i have ran:

```
ifconfig
- Only displays lo information

lspci
- Both the Network controller and the Ethernet controller show up

lshw -class network
- Both controllers description begins with "*-network UNCLAIMED" (which looks suspicious)

rfkill list
- Does not display anything

iwconfig
- Only displays lo
```

I have also tried `sudo service network-manager restart`, but that has been useless. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the linux-image-extra did not get installed with a kernel update.
Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)`
Then reboot